# I have updated yarn with brew and I am no longer able to run the yarn command

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

I have updated yarn with brew and I am no longer able to run the yarn command. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling from brew and npm and clearing all caches but have had no success. The current installed version is 1.22.4.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/..../.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.0.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to see [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5168)?

Answer (score 5):

Erase the config file:

`rm ~/.yarnrc`

I did this now and worked.

Comment: Try `rm ./.yarnrc` too.